# Joint distribution is absolute continuous with respect to product of marginal distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the following:

> Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables with joint distribution $Q$ (For simplicity, assume $Q$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$). Let $\mu$,$\nu$ be marginal distribution of $X,Y$ respectively. Is it true $Q$ absolute continuous with respect to $\mu\times \nu$?

For rectangles, $\mu\times \nu(A\times B)=0$ certainly implies $Q(A\times B)=0$. However, I have difficulty generalize this to all measurable sets. (Personally I believe this is true.)

I tried to use $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. Let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the class of sets satisfying the statement: If $\mu\times \nu(A)=0$, then $Q(A)=0$. Then try to proof $\mathcal{G}$ includes all measurable sets. However, $\mathcal{G}$ is not a $\lambda$ system. i.e. It is not closed under complement. Is there any other ways  to prove this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Consider the case where $X=Y$ and $X \sim U([0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, it's not in general. Consider the measure $Q$ supported on the main diagonal $\Delta=\{(x, x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$Q(A)=\int_{X(A\cap\Delta)}f(x)\,dx$$
where $X:(x,y)=x$, and  $f$ is a density function over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $Y(x,y)=y$. It is easy to check that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$, however
$Q\not\ll  P\otimes P$.